# Char difference between UISearchBar and UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uisearchbar

I'm using `AFNetWorking` POST request to send strings typed by users to my server.

Depending on where the string is caught from, the chars used don't seam to be the same.
For exemple, the <s>simple quote</s> **EDIT**: apostrophe used by a `UITextField` is

> '

and the one used by `UISearchBar` is

> ’

As result, my server can utf8_decode the first one, but not the second one. So I've temporary fixed this issue using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:`, but I can't ensure that some other chars can be replaced by strange ones in the `UISearchBar`.

Is their any settings to apply to the `UISearchBar` to force it to use the same chars as the `UITextField`.
Alternatively, maybe is there a method to apply to the string caught from the `UISearchBar` to use the correct chars ?

Comment: How can you type the first one? I only can type ‘ for both UITextField and UISearchBar

Comment: It's from a French keyboard ; However, I've got the same char using an English(US) keyboard. This char is basically written in my UITextField, or in inputs within UIWebView. I've only have `’` in my UISearchBar

Comment: Rectification : `’` appears in my inputs from UIWebView with the French keyboard

Comment: In my opinion, you did good job in this case. Using `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:` is a good idea. I'm not sure that you can handle every character.

Comment: Ok, my bad. The character causing trouble is not a single quote but an apostrophe